# How to send and receive errors for form validation without using $_GET - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to send and receive errors in php form validation without having to use the $_GET method. What I thought I would do was create an errors array in my functions.php (reusable functions and variables) file like so:

```
$errors = array();
```

And manipulate that errors array like so:

```
//do work with errors array
        //set error into array
        function setError($error){
            $errors[] = $error;
        }

        //get information from array
        function getError(){
            return $errors;
        }

        //empty errors array
        function emptyErrorsArray(){
            $errors[] = null;
        }

        //print errors array
        function printErrorsArray(){
            var_dump($errors);
        }
```

However when I do the above method, I get no feedback to my form as the errors array says NULL the whole time. I tried setting the $errors array to a global variable but that didn't work out so well for me as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using if else statements for PHP validation like so :

```
if(condition)
{

do this

}
else 
{

$errors[] = "your error message" 

} 

after that go just under the body tag and in php blocks put:

if($errors != "")

{

foreach($errors as $error)

{

echo $error;

}

}

This is to display the errors
```

Comment: This requires inline php correct? The only inline php I would like is the one that displays the error code